# Query to compare dates patients are missing from hospital census

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a hospital bed census that is triggered and creates a date/time stamped row in a table. when the bed check portion is done it labels the event census. i have found that some patients on days they were in the hospital have not been timestamped with the event census.  I am trying to write a query to capture all patients that may have had this issue.
i need to capture the patients between their admit and discharge dates, and then any day they do not have a time stamp event of census. for example, this patient does not have a census on the 12th or 13th but does on the 14th.  i want to be able to pull this pat_id and dates they are not stamped with census.

```
11-APR-2019 11:59:00 PM CENSUS
12-APR-2019 03:12:00 PM TRANSFER OUT
12-APR-2019 03:12:00 PM TRANSFER IN
14-APR-2019 07:06:00 AM PATIENT UPDATE
14-APR-2019 11:40:00 AM TRANSFER OUT
14-APR-2019 11:40:00 AM TRANSFER IN
14-APR-2019 11:59:00 PM CENSUS
```

I created a calendar portion to my query. then i created a query to capture patients in a time frame. from there i am a bit stuck.

```
DATE1
AS
(select 
to_char(dates,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS WEEK_DATE,
dates, 
to_char(dates,'D') weekday, 
to_char(dates,'mm') m_onth, 
to_char(dates,'ww') week_of_year, 
to_char(dates,'dd') month_day,
to_char(dates,'ddd') Year_day,
SUBSTR(dates,1,2) AS WEEKDATE
from (SELECT TRUNC(to_date(v.yyyy,'YYYY'),'YY') +LEVEL - 1 DATES 
FROM ( SELECT 2019 yyyy FROM dual ) v 
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 366
)
)
,
ADT 
AS (select distinct
adt.pat_id,
peh.y_mrn,
adt.DEPARTMENT_ID,
adp.department_name,
--peh.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,
to_char(peh.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS HOSP_ADMSN_TIME2,
--peh.HOSP_DISCH_TIME,
to_char(peh.HOSP_DISCH_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS HOSP_DISCH_TIME2,
adt.effective_time,
to_char(aDT.effective_time,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EFFECT_DATE,
--LEAD(adt.effective_time) over (partition by ADT.pat_id order by ADT.pat_id, adt.effective_time) AS NEXT_EFF_DATE,
--CASE WHEN adt.event_type_c =6 THEN adt.effective_time END AS CENSUS_DATE,
et.title as event_type,
adt.event_type_c,
peh.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C,
Adt.event_subtype_c--,
--LAG(adt.effective_time) over (partition by ADT.pat_id order by ADT.pat_id, adt.effective_time) AS PREV_EFF_DATE
from 
clarity_adt adt
left OUTER join 
 pat_enc_hsp peh
 on
peh.pat_enc_csn_id = adt.pat_enc_csn_id
left outer join
clarity_dep adp 
on adt.department_id = adp.department_id
left OUTER join 
zc_event_type et 
on adt.event_type_c = et.event_type_c
where 
adt.effective_time between '08-apr-2019' and '15-apr-2019' 
order by adt.effective_time 
)
,
ADT2
AS
(
SELECT-- DISTINCT
D.WEEK_DATE,
A.HOSP_ADMSN_TIME2,
A.EFFECT_DATE,
A.PAT_ID,
CASE WHEN D.WEEK_DATE IS NOT NULL AND A.EFFECT_DATE IS NULL AND A.event_type <> 'CENSUS' THEN 1
WHEN D.WEEK_DATE IS NOT NULL AND A.EFFECT_DATE IS NULL AND A.event_type IS NULL THEN 1 
WHEN D.WEEK_DATE IS NOT NULL AND A.EFFECT_DATE IS NOT NULL AND A.event_type <> 'CENSUS' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
END AS NO_ADT_INFO,
A.event_type,
A.HOSP_DISCH_TIME2
FROM
DATE2 D
LEFT OUTER JOIN
ADT A
ON 
D.WEEK_DATE = A.EFFECT_DATE
ORDER BY 
D.WEEK_DATE)
```

i would like to end up with the patient id, the day of the week they have no census, the hosp admission & discharge dates

```
PAT_ID  WEEK_DATE   EVENT_TYPE  HOSP_ADMSN_TIME HOSP_DISCH_TIME
ABCDEF  4/12/2019   NO CENSUS   4/10/2019   4/19/2019
ABCDEF  4/13/2019   NO CENSUS   4/10/2019   4/19/2019
GHIJK   4/8/2019    NO CENSUS   4/2/2019    4/12/2019
GHIJK   4/11/2019   NO CENSUS   4/2/2019    4/12/2019
```

Comment: Which database? Can you post some sample data and expected output?

Comment: i cant post a screen shot and i do have sample data in the post, it just doesnt format correctly.

Comment: thank  you for updating that for me!  i guess i need to put the sample data and out come in the code section?  where was it placed so i know going forward

Comment: @sharona . . . You mention a table with a row for a census.  Then you show a really complicated query referencing lots of different tables.  I'm lost on what your data really looks like.

Comment: boneist updated it for me,  i am trying the cte query provided.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample data for two patients:

```
  events(pat_id, event_date, event_type) as (
    select 'ABCD', to_date('2019-04-11 23:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'CENSUS'         from dual union all
    select 'ABCD', to_date('2019-04-12 15:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'TRANSFER OUT'   from dual union all
    select 'ABCD', to_date('2019-04-12 15:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'TRANSFER IN'    from dual union all
    select 'ABCD', to_date('2019-04-14 07:06', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'PATIENT UPDATE' from dual union all
    select 'ABCD', to_date('2019-04-14 11:40', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'TRANSFER OUT'   from dual union all
    select 'ABCD', to_date('2019-04-14 11:40', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'TRANSFER IN'    from dual union all
    select 'ABCD', to_date('2019-04-14 23:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'CENSUS'         from dual union all
    select 'GHIJ', to_date('2019-05-17 23:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'CENSUS'         from dual union all
    select 'GHIJ', to_date('2019-05-19 23:59', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'CENSUS'         from dual ),
  peh(pat_id, hosp_admsn_time, hosp_disch_time) as (
    select 'ABCD', date '2019-04-11', date '2019-04-14' from dual union all
    select 'GHIJ', date '2019-05-17', date '2019-05-20' from dual ),
```

You can create recursive query generating days for each patient and check if there is `CENSUS` event for each of these days:

```
with cte(pat_id, num, adm, dis) as (
    select pat_id, 0, hosp_admsn_time, hosp_disch_time from peh
    union all
    select pat_id, num + 1, adm, dis from cte where num < dis - adm)
select pat_id, day, 'NO CENSUS' info, adm, dis
  from (select pat_id, adm + num day, adm, dis from cte) d
  where not exists (
    select 1 
      from events 
      where pat_id = d.pat_id and trunc(event_date) = d.day and event_type = 'CENSUS')
  order by pat_id, day;
```

Result:

```
PAT_ID DAY         INFO      ADM         DIS
------ ----------- --------- ----------- -----------
ABCD   2019-04-12  NO CENSUS 2019-04-11  2019-04-14
ABCD   2019-04-13  NO CENSUS 2019-04-11  2019-04-14
GHIJ   2019-05-18  NO CENSUS 2019-05-17  2019-05-20
GHIJ   2019-05-20  NO CENSUS 2019-05-17  2019-05-20
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1d19167a9e60d0f9a805389aec7a863a)</sup>**